# angular-ui-grid nested in angular-ui-layout with 100% height

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to show an angular-ui-grid in one of the containers/panes of an angular-ui-layout. The container should contain a toolbar at the top and the remaining space should be filled by either a chart or the corresponding data table which I tried to solve with a flexgrid and ng-include.
My problem is that I don't get the ui-grid to initialize correctly when first shown and it does not fill the remaining space. Also it does not reliably resize when I resize the browser window, sometimes it does not grow accordingly, sometimes it does not shrink usually it's the scrollbars that are misaligned.

I tried using handleWindowResize and ui-grid-auto-resize to no avail.

The ui-layout is this:

```
<div ui-layout="{flow : 'column'}"  >
    <div ui-layout-container size="20%"> 
      <ul>
        <li>Item 1</li>
        <li>Item 2</li>
        <li>Item 3</li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div ui-layout-container>

      <div style="height:100%;display:flex;flex-flow:column;padding:10px">

        <form role="form" style="padding-bottom:10px">
          <label>Toolbar</label>
          <button ng-click="showAnalysis1=true">Analysis 1</button>
          <button ng-click="showAnalysis1=false">Analysis 2</button>
        </form>

        <form role="form" style="padding-bottom:10px">
          <label>Sub-Toolbar</label>
          <button ng-click="showChart=true">Show chart</button>
          <button ng-click="setShowChart(false)">Show table</button>
        </form>

        <div class="analysis-container" ng-show="showAnalysis1" ng-include="'analysis1.html'">
        </div>

        <div class="analysis-container" ng-show="!showAnalysis1" ng-include="'analysis2.html'">
        </div>

      </div>

    </div>
 </div>
```

And the ui-grid is in an ng-include together with a dummy chart, f.e.

```
<div ng-show="showChart">
  Here goes the chart for analysis 1...
</div>

<div ng-show="!showChart" class="my-grid-container">
  <div  ui-grid="tableOptions" class="my-grid" ui-grid-auto-resize>
  </div>  
</div>
```

The following plnkr shows this in context:

http://plnkr.co/edit/gIynXCdy7Kkyl0iwiBid?p=preview

To reproduce:

- press either Analysis1 or Analysis2
- press Show table
- resize the browser window several times

Please ignore the ui-layout splitter for now. At the moment I am only interested in resizing the browser window and having the ui-grid fill the remaining space at all.

Answer (score 1):

I see you have correctly added the directive *ui-grid-auto-resize*, but you also must specify it as a module dependency for your module:

```
angular.module('x', ['ui.layout', 'ui.grid','ui.grid.autoResize'])
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/8VmwsvBGnbtZNsjDL95C?p=preview

Comment: Thanks, that seems to solve the initialization problem. The other problem is, though, that the grid does not fill the remaining height correctly. If you set the grid height fixed to f.e. only 200px, you see that the green container correctly resizes because it has height=100% and is in a flex=1 container. When I set the grid height to 100%, though, the grid exceeds the container and scrollbars appear. I also tried to set the grid height to calc(100% - 150px), f.e., which doesn't work at all! The grid then falls back to a fixed value and doesn't scale at all. Any idea?